# Differentiation cross checking

Tags: derivatives

I have to differentiate the following-
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^n + 1}{n + 1}
$$
The answer I got is:
$$
\frac{nx ^{n - 1}}{n + 1}
$$
Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume you're using the quotient rule - Can you write out your solution step by step?

Comment: Yep! For checking your answers, its probably quicker to check on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28%28%28x%5En%29+%2B+1%29+%2F+%28n+%2B+1%29%29) says you're right. Also, for next time, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math. It makes it much more readable.

Comment: @battletwink69 I think you misread, the denominator is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is redundant with another answers, but I will explain it step by step just in case.

$$\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x} \left(\frac{ x^n +1}{n+1}\right)\stackrel{(1)}{=}\dfrac{1}{n+1}\,\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left(x^n +1\right)\stackrel{(2)}{=}\dfrac{1}{n+1}(nx^{n-1})=\dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{n+1}.$$

(1) The denominator is constant with respect to $x$, so we can take it out of the derivative.

(2) $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left(x^n +1\right)=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} x^n +\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} 1=nx^{n-1}+0=nx^{n-1}.$